# Powershell parameter sets, how to get one parameter from each set but not both?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write what seems very simple but I've been going at this for hours and still not able to get what I need.

I have a PowerShell script which will be used for starting up OR shutting down virtual machines.  I want to user to specify either a ResourceGroup name, an individual VM name or a text file with the names of the VMs.

This script is used for Azure but the question is specific to the param() declaration.

I have tried every combination I can think of here, making parameters parts of parameter sets, making them mandatory, not mandatory, etc. but I have not been able to get this right.

Any help is appreciated!

```
param (
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByResourceGroup')]
    [string]$ResourceGroup,

    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFile')]
    [string]$File,

    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByName')]
    [string]$Name,

    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByResourceGroup')]
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByFile')]
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByName')]
    [switch]$Start,

    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByResourceGroup')]
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByFile')]
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByName')]
    [switch]$Stop
)
```

The user should be able to pass in EITHER:
-ResourceGroup 
OR
-File 
OR
-Name

AND

pass in either:
-Start
OR
-Stop

Not both!

I think I have this correct for the first set but I can't get the -Start and -Stop to be exclusive.

Get-help says this:

```
SYNTAX
    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -ResourceGroup <String> [-Start] [-Stop] [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -File <String> [-Start] [-Stop] [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -Name <String> [-Start] [-Stop] [<CommonParameters>]


I am looking for something more like this:

SYNTAX
    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -ResourceGroup <String> -Start [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -File <String> -Start [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -Name <String> -Start [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -ResourceGroup <String> -Stop [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -File <String> -Stop [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -Name <String> -Stop [<CommonParameters>]
```

Just to close this out... I wound up changing this a bit (needs changed and so did the code).  As others suggested, I agree that what I was trying to do probably wasn't possible anyway.  Also, I am handling the possibility that the user will choose both -Start and -Stop or neither in code.  Thanks to everyone for your comments!

```
SYNTAX
    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -Name <String> -ResourceGroup <String> [-Start] [-Stop] [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\Set-AzureVM.ps1 -File <String> [-Start] [-Stop] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: Parameter sets are unique from each other.

Comment: I would personally just have a single switch with a `ValidateSet('Stop','Start')`. You can also just have both with logic in the script that handles the discrepancy. I feel you can't do what you want with the number of parameters you have.

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. You might consider breaking the functionality up into two separate scripts.

- Start-AzureVM.ps1
- Stop-AzureVM.ps1

Alternatively you can use the switch `-stop` to do both starting and stopping. by default `-stop` will evaluate to `$false` in your script or function.

```bsh
# implicitly start the vm
Set-AzureVM.ps1 -Name <String>

# explicitly stop the vm
Set-AzureVM.ps1 -Name <String> -stop
```

```bsh
function Set-AzureVM () {
    param(
        [Parameter (Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'ByFile')]
        [string]$File,

        [Parameter (Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'ByName')]
        [string]$Name,

        [switch]$Stop
    )
    if($Stop){
        Write-Host 'Stopping VM'
    }
    if(!$stop){
        Write-Host 'Starting VM'
    }
}

Get-Command Set-AzureVM -Syntax
```

```
Set-AzureVM -File <string> [-Stop] [<CommonParameters>]

Set-AzureVM -Name <string> [-Stop] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  FYI, the code was originally in two different scripts but the work item acceptance criteria was for one script.